# Definition of bootstraping and routing - MVC Pattern

Tags: php, url-routing, bootstrapping

I have been learning the MVC Pattern and think i have a good grasp on what it entails, and now for practice im going to implement my own MVC framework and website.

I have read many tutorials, some saying i should have a bootstrap class and a route class, aswell as others just having a route class, which has me very confused as to what the bootstrap actually does?

I know the router pulls in the requested URI, breaks it down and sends to the needed controller for whichever module is needed.

I just dont know what the bootstrap should be used for?

My ideas is that it should:

- be the only file included from the index.php
- have autoloading functions in it
- instantiate the router class
- include the main config file for db access, defining web directories etc.

Does this sound about right?

Also if i access the router class via the bootstrap should the router pass the correct controller name back to the bootstrap to then pass the data onto the correct controller or should the router directly send the data to the correct class?

Thanks Tom

Comment: Download a couple MVC frameworks and study their code. It will give you a good idea of what a bootstrap file is. Theory will only get you so far.

Comment: "MVC" doesn't really define rules for what you're asking; it just means that you will have MVC files.  Different frameworks do routing, bootstrapping, config their own ways.  Your ideas for a bootstrap sound fine though.

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with bootstrapping or routing.